# output an array from locales yml file to erb using a loop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, loops, yaml, erb

I'm new to ruby. I have an array from **config\locales\en.yml**

```
sample_array:
 - list1
 - list2
 - list3
 - list4
```

I'm trying to output it to erb using a *do* loop

```
<% sample_array.each do |list| %>
 <p><%= list %></p>
<% end %>
```

My expected result:

```
list1

list2

list3

list4
```

Instead, I get an error saying ***undefined local variable or method***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Values in locale files are retrieved with `I18n.t('key')` or just `t('key')`. Try

```
<% t('sample_array').each do |item| %>
 <p><%= item %></p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I have this huge file that has a lot of arrays. You saved me a lot of time!